# Remote developement and debugging with eclipse,python,remote system explorer, raspberrypi : Import Error

Tags: python, eclipse, raspberry-pi, pydev

I am working with a Raspberrypi 1 model B+ and python and I want to remotely debug it for my application since I am building a mobile robot. I installed the pydev and ssh(Remote System Explorer) plugin from eclipse marketplace.

**I am getting an import error:** `no module named RPi.GPIO.`

Can anyone help me through this?

I checked the python versions on my pi and tried to use those as my interpreters but that also did not help to remove the error.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents/RobotMovementTest $ python --version  
Python 2.7.13  
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents/RobotMovementTest $ python3 --version  
Python 3.5.3

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  
import time  
from math import sin,cos,atan2,degrees,fabs  

GPIO.setwarnings(False)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bosede1\eclipse-workspace\RemoteSystemsTempFiles\10.2.114.170\home\pi\Documents\RobotMovementTest\ddrobot.py", line 9, in <module>
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  
ImportError: No module named RPi.GPIO
```